# how to pass s3 event as input to step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am new on aws so please understand if I miss something,
So i want to create step function that trigger the lambda.

I have a situation like: `lambda_A` copy file from one s3 bucket to another like `bucket_1` to `bucket_2` and in same lambda i am invoking the step function with boto3 client. in the step function i am triggering the another `lambda_B` but `lambda_B` require s3 event of `bucket_2`.

Now the problem is how can i pass s3 event of `bucket_2` as input to step function ?

**Note**: I tried creating another lambda that triggered from `bucket_2` and in that lambda i started the step function with s3 event **however** i cannot create another lambda just for this small work.

If anyone have any idea about this situation please share.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would pass the event as `input` when you start your SFN.

For example in boto3, when you use [start_execution](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.start_execution) to start your SFN, you would pass the S3 event as an `input` parameter:

```
response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn='string',
    name='string',
    input=json.dumps(event)
)
```

Comment: yes you are correct i am doing exactly what you said, but in my case i have s3 event of bucket_1 not bucket_2. so my question  is still there how can i start step function with s3 event of bucket_2.

Comment: i think my question is not valid or i dont know

Comment: @dera I think you can't do this direclty if I understand your use-case correctly. You can instead maybe pass the event to sqs and have step function to get the event from there.